# Does it make sense to have a matrix with sets as elements?

Tags: matrices

I'm aware matrix multiplication or adition may not be defined(or at least not in the usual way), but is there some context where matrix consisting of sets actually makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia defines a matrix as a rectangular array of "numbers, symbols, or expressions" - that does not seem to include sets, but there is no reason you couldn't define an array of sets if it is useful to do so. That would be essentially the same as indexing a bunch of sets by two indices, for example:
 $$\begin{pmatrix} S_{1,1} & S_{1,2} & \cdots & S_{1,n}\\ S_{2,1} & S_{2,2} & \cdots & S_{2,n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ S_{m,1} & S_{m,2} & \cdots & S_{m,n} \end{pmatrix}.$$
It is much more succinct to write $(S_{i,j})_{1\leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n}$. So is there any advantage to writing the sets in a matrix? Probably not. As you noted, there probably won't be a notion of matrix multiplication (unless you are working with a ring of sets).

In short, sure you could define a matrix of sets. But it probably wouldn't be any more useful than just indexing your sets with two indices.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any desire to add or multiply then theoretically you can chose any thing to be an element of your matrix.